# How many NPCs are in Terraria Android version?

Tags: terraria-mobile

I want to know how many NPCs are there in the mobile version of Terraria. I am not getting a proper answer on the Terraria Wiki, it is showing the NPCs from the computer version.

Answer (score 4):

There are 18 NPCs that currently exist in all versions of Terraria Mobile (includes both iOS and Android). This number does not include the Santa Claus and the Old Man NPCs.

[This](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/NPC) is probably the page you were looking at. All NPCs that **do not** have a little computer next to their name ([image: Computer symbol]) are avaliable in Terraria Mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Well there are actually a lot to NPCs from what I know they are

The guide
The merchant
The nurse
The arms dealer
The demolitionist
The clothed
The mechanic
The old man
The goblin tinkerer
The wizard
The truffle
The pirate
The dye trader
The painter
The hair stylist
The angler
The steampunker
The cyborg
The witch doctor
Santa